# react: recalling the dialog via a state change

Tags: reactjs, state, react-bootstrap, setstate

I have a dropdown list and a dialog that displays when item (with class `dialogselected`) in the dropdown list is selected

Code:

```
// function is triggered when an item in the drop-down list is selected
handleSelect = (eventKey: any, event: any) => {

    this.setState({
        selected_id:        eventKey,
        is_activated:       event.target.classList.contains('dialogselected')
    });
}

// display a drop-down list and a modal dialog
render() {
    return (
        <>
            <Dropdown>
                <Dropdown.Menu>
                    <Dropdown.Item 
                        onSelect = {this.handleSelect}
                    >...</Dropdown.Item>
                </Dropdown.Menu>
            </Dropdown>
            {this.state.is_activated ? <MyDialog /> : null}
        </>
    );
}
```

When an item with the class `dialogselected` is selected, the dialog is displayed.

If I close the dialog and select the same item again, the dialog will not be displayed again **because the state has not changed**, i.e. `is_activated` was `true` and remains so.

Can you advise how to correctly fix this situation?

I.e. the dialog needs to be called repeatedly, i.e. we need to somehow let the geast know that the state has been yanked

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you could pass a little bit more code, so we can see the bigger picture.

My initial guess is that there is something wrong with `event.target.classList.contains('dialogselected')`, maybe you are not toggling it on an element properly.

Comment: I checked - selecting an item from the drop-down list is correct, setting the state is correct, but since the state does not change, react does not respond to setting the state - this is the problem. Maybe you need to call the render method directly again? The dialog is displayed when the state `this.state.is_activated` changes, and it does not change if you select the same item in the drop-down list, if you first select any other item, then the desired item, then everything works fine